# Abstraction in php

Tags: php, abstract

I have few external services in PHP and a config class - a singleton class to take config list from .ini file.
For each class I do something like the folwing in the constructor:

```
$this->config = ConfigClass::getConfig()
```

do I need to declare an abstract class and only their in the constructor put that config class and than just extend the class?

For example: I want to also add logger
I will glad to get some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract classes are used as a template for derived class. Any method with the abstract keyword declared in the base abstract class must be overwritten in the derived class.

See [php.net documentation on abstract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

For your example it is sufficient to do:

```
class Base {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = ConfigClass::getConfig();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
}
```

However, note - if you want to put something in the derived class' constructor, you have to invoke it explicitly, like so:

```
class Base {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = ConfigClass::getConfig();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Other code
    }
}
```